How to convert String with format "2024-08-19 00:20:04.0 +2:00" to datetime format in Scala
I have string and I wanted to converted to toLocalDateTime with the same format. But when I try the same format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S Z" it failed to convert because it did not parse the timezone offset :
LocalDateTime.parse("2024-08-19 00:20:04.0 +2:00",java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S Z"))

It gives below errors :
 LocalDateTime.parse("2024-08-19 00:20:04.0 +2:00",java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S Z"))
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2024-08-19 00:20:04.0 +2:00' could not be parsed at index 22
  at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2056)
  at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1958)
  at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:494)
  ... 30 elided

I try to replace Z by z but the same issue , also I try replace Z by a still the same error is there are a way to convert string contain timezone offset like "+2:00" to datetime in below format : "2024-08-19 00:20:04.0 +2:00"

You don't have a LocalDateTime there, btw. You have an OffsetDateTime

With that in mind, try DateTimerFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").appendLiteral(" ").appendOffset("+H:mm", "").toFormatter(); then use that to parse your String

LocalDateTime is date + time. OffsetDateTime is date + time + offset. ZonedDateTime is date + time + time zone. Instant is date + time in UTC.

by the way, if your offset was +02:00 you would be able to parse it using XXX or xxx

You need a DateTimeFormatter with a custom format as shown in the example below:
DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)
                    .appendLiteral(' ')
                    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
                    .appendLiteral(' ')
                    .appendOffset("+H:mm", "")
                    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        

Use it to parse your date-time string into an OffsetDateTime from which you can drop the offset and get the remaining part in the default format of LocalDateTime by using OffsetDateTime#toLocalDateTime.
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)
                .appendLiteral(' ')
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
                .appendLiteral(' ')
                .appendOffset("+H:mm", "")
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2024-08-19 00:20:04.0 +2:00", dtf);

        // Dropping the timezone offset from odt
        LocalDateTime ldt = odt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}

Output:
2024-08-19T00:20:04

Online Demo
As commented by stefanobaghino, if you want to convert this OffsetDateTime to a LocalDateTime of a specific timezone offset, first you need to use OffsetDateTime#withOffsetSameInstant and then drop the offset from it.
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)
                .appendLiteral(' ')
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
                .appendLiteral(' ')
                .appendOffset("+H:mm", "")
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2024-08-19 00:20:04.0 +2:00", dtf);

        // Converting odt to an OffsetDateTime in the system's default timezone
        // Replace ZoneId.systemDefault() with a specific timezone e.g.
        // ZoneId.of("America/New_York") as per your requirement
        OffsetDateTime odtInSystemTimeZone = odt.withOffsetSameInstant(
                ZoneId.systemDefault()
                        .getRules()
                        .getOffset(odt.toInstant()));

        // Dropping the timezone offset from odtInSystemTimeZone
        LocalDateTime ldt = odtInSystemTimeZone.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}

Output when you run it on a system with default offset as of UTC:
2024-08-18T22:20:04

Online Demo
Replace ZoneId.systemDefault() with a specific timezone e.g. ZoneId.of("America/New_York") as per your requirement.
Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from Trail: Date Time.

Your online demo doesn't show your code; it looks like the initial template.

Thanks for pointing it out. There seems to be some problem with IDEOne currently. I'm going to include the code in the answer.

You can also use this dtf to parse directly into a LocalDateTime.

Yes, but I wanted the OP to learn that his date-time string has an offset and therefore, the closest date-time class is OffsetDateTime.

Yes, Ideone.com has been wiping out any initial code on first execution. So execute the empty template once, then write your code after (and copy all text as a backup). The site was apparently hacked badly in recent months, with bogus screens appearing, then eventually recovered. Seems this problem has been occurring since then. If anyone knows of an alternative to Ideone.com, please post.

@Basil workaround: opening the editor works -- press RUN without entering any code, then select edit top-left-corner, enter the code and then execute (again) - proof - Alternative: Try It Online

Important: toLocalDateTime() just drops the offset. If you want to convert the time to a specific time zone you need to first call .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId) or .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset) first. Example (in Scala): https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/2hw4zk4OTuWLCobXNA15yQ/7

Thanks all for the valuable suggestion regarding the workaround for IDEOne. With the suggested workaround, the link to the online demo correctly points to the code.

Thanks, @stefanobaghino for the useful information. I have incorporated your comment in the answer.

ideone demo worked for me
